# DirectX11 CopyResource leave right bottom uncopyed

Tags: directx, directx-11

D3D level is D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0.

I made texture2d with same desc setting.

```
    CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    desc.Width = width;
    desc.Height = height;
    desc.MipLevels = 1;
    desc.ArraySize = _array_size;
    desc.Format =DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    desc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

But when I render shader resource view for stencil, the right bottom is leave uncopied like below.
Depths are copied well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3fNZ.png)

The original texture don't make this strange results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJMBO.png)

I made depth stencil buffer with this state for rectangle in the picture to make stencil value bigger than 0. For the man upon the rect, with same the desc but stencilEnable off to make stencil value 0.

```
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC));

desc.DepthEnable      = true;
desc.DepthWriteMask   = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
desc.DepthFunc        = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;
desc.StencilEnable    = true;
desc.StencilReadMask  = 0xFF;
desc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

desc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
desc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
desc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR_SAT;
desc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
```

I used the code below to copy the stencil. The only difference of drawing the original stencil value is just this 1 line.

```
D3D_Context->CopyResource(copy->GetTex2D(), origin->GetTex2D());
```

And draw stencil with this state. I tried to draw the rectangle not the man.

```
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC desc;
ZeroMemory(&desc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC));

desc.DepthEnable      = false;
desc.DepthWriteMask   = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
desc.DepthFunc        = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;
desc.StencilEnable    = true;
desc.StencilReadMask  = 0x01;
desc.StencilWriteMask = 0x01;

desc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
desc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
desc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
desc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
```

Comment: Please add the code for ``CopyResource``. Also, what ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL`` are you using?

Comment: I amended. The level is D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0.